# Google Play meaning of "Installs"

Tags: android, google-play

Can somebody tell me what is the meaning of Installs: 100-500.
What Google Play counts? Dayly installs? Monthly installs? Total installs of application.

I`m trying to see applications of people and see how much they were installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the total count of installs that is shown on the page, under it you will find a chart of the last 30 days, which you can use as an indication to see if it is still growing alot or the opposite.

Answer (score 6):

That's the total amount of installs of the applications/game. But google play does not show the amount of devices that has the applications installed at the momment. It´s a shame because an application can be installed 5000 times but only be installed in 500 because of 4500 desinstallations

Answer (score 1):

it means between 100-500 have installed it total